# GUI and AI Logical Flow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I whipped up a basic voice assistant using what I know on python with some research, as a self learning project.

[Link to the code is here](https://pastebin.com/tRYF0gS6)

I am basically converting the audio to text and then splitting it to look for keywords and then trigger a response or an action so to speak, which is not very intelligent but it's working for the time being.

How else can I look for keywords, is there a better approach, an efficient way, if you will, than a thousand lines of ifs and elifs?

Another problem I have is, I built a GUI interface for this program so I could interact with it at the click of a button but the problem is, the window isn't responding after clicking the button, turns out it's a known problem and I don't know how to get around it as I don't know the concept of threads and processes and queues. I am hoping that someone could help me with my problem.

I would like to point out that if I have to do any learning for this project, I would be interested to do that since the idea behind this whole project is learning how to code or build an AI, which may sound stupid

PS: I implemented, well, sort of did, always listen feature or keep running feature by keeping the function in a while loop. I would like to find a way for a voice speech trigger as well to wake up the assistant. Any help in that aspect would be much appreciated.

And also, help me set a name to this assistant, preferably female.

The code is here:

```
import os
import time
import random
import webbrowser
import tkinter as tk
from gtts import gTTS
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from playsound import playsound
import speech_recognition as sr
from weather import Weather, Unit

def startAssistant():
    keepRunning = 1
    while keepRunning is 1:
        mainFunction()
        if mainFunction() is 0: break

def doNothing(): print("I don't do anything apart from printing this line of course!")

def mainFunction():

    f = open("assistant.txt", "a")

    # Printing what a user is saying for better user experience
    def say(text):
        print(text)
        f.write("\n" + text + "\n")
        return text

    # This function will take inputs to talk back
    def talkBack(text, recordingName):
        # Variable Declaration
        extension = ".mp3"

        # Synthesising the reponse as speech
        tts = gTTS(text=say(text), lang="en-us")

        # Saving the response files
        fileName = recordingName + extension
        audioPath = "audioFiles\\"
        responseFile = audioPath + fileName

        # Checking to see if the file is already created
        if not os.path.exists(responseFile):
            tts.save(responseFile)
        # Playing the audio
        playsound(responseFile)

    # Initialising things here
    recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
    microphone = sr.Microphone()

    # Asking for input and saving that
    with microphone as source:
        print ("Speak:")
        audio = recognizer.listen(source)

    # Converting audio into text
    convertedAudio = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
    convertedAudioSplit = convertedAudio.split()

    # Printing what was picked up when the user Spoke and also logging it
    print("\n" + convertedAudio + "\n")
    f.write("\n" + convertedAudio + "\n")

    # Start of a conversation
    if "hello" in convertedAudioSplit:
        talkBack("Hi, how are you doing today?", "hello")

    # Wishing people based on the time of the day  
    elif "morning" in convertedAudioSplit:
        talkBack("Good morning! The sun's shining bright, let's head out for a run. We'll get back and make a healthy breakfast for ourselves", "morning")
    elif "afternoon" in convertedAudioSplit:
        talkBack("Good afternoon! You must be hungry right about now, why don't you break for lunch?", "afternoon")
    elif "night" in convertedAudioSplit:
        talkBack("Nighty night sleepy pot! Get a good night's sleep while I learn more to be more helpful to you tomorrow.", "night")

    # Getting her information
    elif "doing" in convertedAudioSplit:
        talkBack("I am doing very good, Thank you for asking!", "doing")

    # Making the assistant open web browser with a URL
    elif "Google" in convertedAudioSplit:
        talkBack("Okay, lets get you to Google.", "google")
        # Opening the browser with the required URL
        webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com/", new = 1)

    # Brings the weather report
    elif "weather" in convertedAudioSplit:
        weatherVariable = Weather(unit=Unit.CELSIUS)
        location = weatherVariable.lookup_by_location('bangalore')
        condition = location.condition.text
        talkBack("It is {0} right now in Bengaluru.".format(condition), "weather")

    # Exiting the program on user's consent
    elif "exit" in convertedAudioSplit:
        talkBack("Sure, if that's what you want! I will miss you, have a good day.", "exit")
        return 0

    # If there is an UnknownValueError, this will kick in
    elif sr.UnknownValueError:
        talkBack("I am sorry, I couldn't quite get what you said. Could you please say that again?", "UnknownValueError")

    # When things go out of the box
    else:
        # Out of scope reply
        talkBack("I am a demo version. When you meet the completed me, you will be surprised.", "somethingElse")
        return 0

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Voice Assistant")
mainFrame = tk.Frame(root, width = 1024, height = 720, bg = "turquoise", borderwidth = 5)

menu = tk.Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
subMenu = tk.Menu(menu)

startButton = tk.Button(mainFrame, text="Interact", command = startAssistant)
startButton.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 1.0, anchor = tk.S)

menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=subMenu)

subMenu.add_command(label="Do Nothing", command=doNothing)
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)

mainFrame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't want to post this as an answer just yet....  would you consider using a wrapper package for tkinter?  PySimpleGUI is a package that makes using tkinter easier and more simple.  There is a machine learning bot example posted with the package Demo_Chatterbot.py that may be of some interest.  If this looks like a reasonable answer, I would be happy to write up something with more information.

Comment: @MikeyB, I would be interested in looking into the options here. Thank you for sharing your view. I would definitely look into it

Answer (score 1):

One potential solution is to use a simpler GUI package.  Perhaps the GUI package [PySimpleGUI](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) would be a fit.  It could solve your GUI problem and free you up to work on the other portions of your project.

Check out the [Chat Demo](https://github.com/MikeTheWatchGuy/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/Demo_Chat.py) that implements a Chat front-end. Therre's also a [Chatterbot Demo](https://github.com/MikeTheWatchGuy/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/Demo_Chatterbot.py) that implements a front-end to the Chatterbot project.

You can start by copying that code and modifying it.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will check this out

Comment: Thank you for your help, I haven't had time to take a look into this project for quite sometime. I had time to kill today, and I read the PySimpleGUI documentation. I found a note that asks users to not implement PySimpleGUI in threads as it is based on tkinter and since tkinter doesn't support threads, this doesn't work.

The work I do includes tasks that take long time before they give the focus back to the GUI window, I need a GUI that doesn't stop responding while the AI is speaking.

Could you please help?

Comment: You can run threads WITH the GUI.   I don't recommend trying to put the GUI into a thread.
As long as you call the GUI on a periodic basis then it won't stop working.

Comment: Okay, I will give it a shot and update the answer if I have a working solution

Comment: I couldn't get it to work! The interface still gets stuck waiting for focus to revert to itself if I don't implement threads. If I run the program with the functionality on one thread and the gui on another with synchronization, both are running individually causing the mic to open multiple times and the whole program crashes.

Comment: If you "starve" the GUI of CPU cycles, it's not going to be responsive.  You HAVE to call a GUI refresh routine every now and then... as often as you wish to have the GUI respond.  The only way to do 2 tasks that both take up CPU time is to thread them.  If you believe there is a bug causing your trouble / crash, then log an issue on Github.  Stackoverflow is not the place to do joint debugging.